# Is there a flexible calculator available that can walk you through complex SQL licensing?

Tags: licensing

The basic license guide for Microsoft SQL Server is 40 pages in length.  This document references still more documents on various topics, options, and definitions used for licensing.  The license that one selects determines the conditions that will trigger additional costs required to stay functional over time.

Is there an accurate application that can be used to determine pricing for the various licensing and project a timeline for potential additional costs as a function of time and growth?

This would be a useful tool for proposal writers, legal teams, and planners.

It is very clear that licensing has become it's own "career track" that favors large business.

A tool or business that could provide an unambiguous set of costs and terms based on list price could be free small to medium sized businesses to move forward on projects with some measure of confidence.

Comment: Such a tool would imply that licensing costs are completely open and rational. Most large vendors, their resellers and their larger customers will negotiate rather than pay suggested retail prices and will treat any discounts and “custom” terms/conditions as privileged information. It is mainly only the smallest vendors that will have one single price list and almost universally that  only the smallest customers are the ones to pay list prices.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can you help me with my software licensing issue?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-issue)

Comment: I agree that most large vendors, their resellers and their larger customers negotiate.  As a small business owner, a tool that navigates the complex licensing and projects likely additional expenses would be extremely useful.

Comment: The "Can you help me with my software licensing issue" was not terribly helpful.

Comment: That's because it is not intented to answer your question, but rather explain you why we can't answer such questions here and why any licensing questions are strictly off topic here. You should ask your reseller, not us.